# "Just" versus "simply"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adverbs

To which extent is *just* interchangeable with *simply*, as in the example?

> It's becoming more than just annoying.
>   It's becoming more than simply annoying.

Is *just* synonym of *simply* in just any case or are there situations where the two adverbs convey slightly different meanings?

Also, Google gives 1,800,000,000 results for *just* and only 295,000,000 results for *simply*. Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Re: Google, "simply", for all I know, is only a word in English, whereas "just" is a word in many languages (English, German, Swedish, Latvian...). Also, there's the given name "Just" and the family name "Just", and Google doesn't care about capitalization.

Comment: Also, "just" has more meanings than "simply", so it's entirely expected that it occurs more often in any given corpus.

Comment: Oh, though of another synonym you can employ: *merely annoying*.

Comment: @RegDwight Indeed, comparing "just" vs. "simply" in Google was short-sighted. I think it should have been "just annoying" vs. "simply annoying". Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Martha Ha, _merely annoying_ -- nice synonym, thanks.

Comment: The idea was to stress the fact that some way of things is annoying beyond some tolerable limit and somethings has to be done about it, etc. So, probably, the initial sentence can be rephrased in a more natural way.

Answer (score 4):

*Just* and *simply* have some overlapping meanings, but definitely do not overlap in all meanings.  In your example, it is a case where they have essentially the same meaning.

However, *just* (the adverb) can also mean "only now".  For example:

> How long have you been here?  — I just got here. (=I arrived right now.)

*Simply* cannot be used in this instance.

(Note: I assume that we are only talking about *just* as an adverb; *just* can be used as an adjective too, meaning "right" or "fair".  I don't think you are concerned about that one, because it is clearly totally different in usage.)

Comment: Yep, sure, in this question I only refer to _just_ as an adverb. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence sounds odd and is incorrect. "Just" and "Simply" do not have the same meaning, however, these can be interchanged in most situations; though not in this one.

Comment: When you say "This is just annoying", it means that it is justified to classify the object, or the act, in question as annoying.

Comment: When you say, "This is simply annoying", it means that you don't need to use your grey matter to know that this is annoying. It's something which is quite obvious.

Comment: @Prateek - I would disagree with your interpretations.  If someone says "this is just annoying" I would take that to mean that it has no other redeeming characteristic.  Similarly, "this is simply annoying" would indicate that it is not complex enough to include additional values.

Comment: Prateek, why does "simply annoying" sound odd to you? It's not at all incorrect, and it means exactly the same thing as "just annoying": merely annoying, with no other remarkably bad characteristics.

Comment: @Martha
 "Simply annoying" doesn't sounds odd; but "this is more than simply annoying" does.

Comment: @Dusty Thats exactly what I meant.

Comment: You haven't got the right sense of 'simply' here. Dusty is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As adverb, *just* means:

- exactly;
- very recently;
- barely; by little;
- simply.

There are then cases where *just* can replaced with *simply* without to change meaning to the sentence.

As examples of usage of *just* the NOAD reports the following sentences:

> That's just what I need.
>   You're a human being, just like everyone else.
>   Conditions were just as bad.
>   I've just seen the local paper.
>   I got here just after nine.
>   They were just interested in making money.

There also phrases where you need to use *just*, as in *just about*, *just as well*, *just in case*, *just a minute*; replace *just* with *simply*, and you get a phrase without sense.

The results obtained from Google don't mean that, as *just* appears more frequently than *simply*, *just* is more preferred. As the words are not synonyms, comparing them is like to compare the number of sentences containing *house* with the number of sentences containing *moon*.
With Google, then (as reported by other comments), you don't obtain results for English only, and you can obtain also results for phrases that are not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

"Just" (adverbial), "merely", "only", and "simply" can mean exactly the same thing in certain contexts. However, as kiamlaluno points out, there are at least four distinct meanings of "just" used as an adverb.

In the example "just as well" provided by kiamlaluno, the meaning of "just" is "equally", but it is not being used an adverb.

Dusty misapplies one of the meanings of "simply" ("not complex enough to include additional values") which is irrelevant to  the case at hand.