# When to use "just"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

The word *just* is one of those overused words that carries little meaning and appears to just clutter up a sentence (oops, did it again).

- When is the use of *just* justified?
- What are better, clearer constructions (e.g. replace *just* with *only*)
- When should the word be dropped altogether?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but similar question asked here: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4861/2242

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say a good rule of thumb is to use it when you need it for clarity or to add a special emphasis.

> There were just three jars of honey left.

This is different from

> There were three jars of honey left.

because it gives the sense that three jars of honey is not a lot, or at least that you don't think it is.

So the answer is no, don't give it up entirely. Just trust yourself to use it less. Think of it as dieting. If you have the willpower, you can write lean sentences.

Answer (score 5):

As other words, use it when it adds a meaning to the sentence, and not just to use it.

> A just and democratic society (it is different from *a democratic society*).
>   We all get our just deserts (it is different from *we all get our deserts*).
>   I've just seen the local paper (it is different from *I've seen the local paper*).
>   They were just interested in making money (it is different from *they were interested in making money*, but it is similar to *they were only interested in making money*).
>   They are just great (it is different from *they are great*).
>   "Simon really messed things up." "Didn't he just?"

<sub>[Reference: The New Oxford American Dictionary.]</sub>

Comment: "I've just seen the local paper" isn't different from "I've just seen the local paper" (and similarly for the "making money" example) :-)

Comment: @psmears: There is a difference.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: well, there is now that you’ve corrected it with the edit :-P

Comment: I don't believe the first two examples are accurate to the question at hand - *just* in those two are short forms of the word *justice*, or at least have that connotation.

Comment: @Will: _just_, in the first two sentences, is not a short for _justice_; try replacing _just_ with _justice_, and you will see it doesn't make sense (also because _justice_ is a noun, and not an adjective). _just_ in the first sentence means _based on or behaving according to what is morally right and fair_; in the second sentence, it means _deserved or appropriate in the circumstances_. [Reference: New Oxford American Dictionary.]

Comment: @kiamlaluno: you cannot replace "just" with "justice" - as you say, one is an adjective, the other a noun. My point was that it is not being used in the same way as the OP's question. Perhaps I was not clear in my comment, but that was what I was getting at. The OP is using it as an adverb; essentially it is taking the place of "only" or "simply", both of which could be substituted for "just" as in Robusto's example.

Comment: @WIll: In fact, the OP is also asking when he should use _just_, and when replace it with something else, using _only_ as example; if he meant _just_ as short for _justice_, then he would not use _only_ as example. If you are referring to my example (as it seems you are doing, because you wrote _I don't believe the first two examples are accurate_), then _just_, as used in the first two examples, is not the "short form of the word _justice_". The OP didn't give any examples; he just asked when to use _just_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Fair enough; I took it to be in a particular context, and yours is a bit broader than mine.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: the OP may not have spelt out that 'just' as an adverb was the focus of the question, but 'just' as an adjective is hardly problematic.  Your 'answer' does not help the OP understand how to use 'just' (for example by explaining the extra meaning that just is providing.  In fact, your answer does not seem even to acknowledge that there is a  difference between the adverbial and adjectival usages.

Answer (score 0):

I've pondered this word many times.  It also has a singular/universal/variant side.

**Universal**
As the Catholic Church says, "It is right and it is just..." where "just" is used to imply law and legality, similar to justice.  This form of "just" applies a meaning that it includes all people, therefore universal.

**Singular**
"I just want to kiss."  Here it means only me, I am the only one who wants something and the thing I want is only a kiss.

**Variant**
Then there are others, "just in time", which is neither universal or singular but in this case it's an approximation to a specific time.

*Just* recently I noticed that *just* this law is not *just* onto Bedouins and their herds.