# Use of "just" in technical writing as an adverb for location

Tags: word-choice, technical, science

I am editing a friend's scientific manuscript, which will ultimately be submitted to a biological journal. He uses "just" as an adverb to describe a location (**emphasis** added by me), e.g.,

> The river's confluence is located **just** downriver from the site.

However, the use of "just" seems too colloquial to me for scientific writing, although I cannot pinpoint exactly why I dislike the use of "just". **Am I correct in my assessment that "just" should be wordsmithed out?** e.g.,

> The river's confluence is located **immediately** downriver from the town.

The exact distance (e.g., 100 m vs 1 km) is not important because this is a caption to map. Also, I have looked at other "just" questions on this site. [This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73444/idiomatic-saying-for-just-over-and-just-under) is similar but non-technical.  [An answer to this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215333/ambiguity-of-just-in-a-context) suggests that "just" can be ambiguous, which might be another reason I might dislike the use of "just". Also, my question is not relevant to [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/when-to-use-just) or [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4861/just-versus-simply) on "just".

Comment: I think your reluctance to use ***just*** in this way simply reflects the fact that the usage was [relatively uncommon until a century or two ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comes+just+after&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomes%20just%20after%3B%2Cc0). Admittedly, there's potential ambiguity in, say, *Some specimens were just too big to be preserved for future analysis*, but I see no ambiguity in your context. It just depends on how "starchy" you want your text to appear.

Comment: 'just' (as used here) sounds a little informal, and probably doesn't work well in technical writing because it is not very specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of "just" in this situation is unnecessary.  The phrase works just as well without it, i.e.:  "The river's confluence is located downriver from the site."

If the attempt is to indicate a small distance, then "The river's confluence is nearby, located downriver from the site."

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. You're solution addresses my concern AND creates a shorter sentence!

Answer (score -1):

JUST is commonly used but that doesn't necessarily rob it of its beauty & worth. In literal writing we write -The comment is just as it is adequate.No harm,you may go with JUST as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not doing literal writing.

Comment: This answer uses a completely different definition of 'just' from the one used in the question.